# Which HTTP Method to use in these RESTFUL use-cases?

Tags: rest

Hopefully someone can help me out on this one.

Consider the following use-cases:

1. Add a Role to a User
2. Remove/Revoking a Role from a User

The interface into the system is RESTFUL.

When **adding** a role the following URL is used:

```
PUT /user/{userId}/role/{roleId}
```

When **removing/revoking** a role from a user the following URL is used:

```
DELETE /user/{userId}/role/{roleId}
```

My gut feeling is that both these RESTFUL calls should be a PUT and the URLs should be amended too:

```
PUT /user/{userId}/register/role/{roleId}
PUT /user/{userId}/revoke/role/{roleId}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating should be done using a POST, and so creating a new role for a user should be a POST rather than a PUT, I would say. It depends if you consider adding a role to be the creation of a role (in which case it's a POST), or the modification of a user (then it's a PUT). The way you've phrased the URL suggests the former to me, so I'd go with POST.

The same argument applies to the revocation of the role. Is that a modification of a user, or the deletion of a role? If the former, then I'd say PUT, if the latter, then DELETE.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see it as a modification of a user myself, because the role already exists. The only creation is the relationship....interesting

Comment: This is why I'm less than convinced about REST. It looks all fine and dandy until you try and phrase the operations, then it gets all woolly.

Comment: It it just as valid to use a PUT to create a resource.  The only condition is that you need to know the roleId in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My own take is that DELETE is usually preferable from a RESTful point of view. You would use PUT if you work through a transaction log -- you don't just remove some permission, you add a transaction removing the permission to your transaction log, which also means each time you do you'll get an unique ID representing that action.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The resource User has an ID as does Role, but the relationship doesn't resulting in no unique resource ID which is why I thought PUT more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution you presented is restful as you are using the Http verbs consistently.  The second solution is not consistent because you are using a PUT to remove something.

If you were to create a resource to represent the transaction of registering and revoking then you could do the following:

```
POST /registrations

POST /revokations
```

Now, in the revoke case, it is more clear that you are creating a resource (a revoke transaction) that has a side effect of removing the role from the user.  The downside is that now you need a POST body that contains the user and the role that is being affected by the transaction.

Your first solution is definitely the best in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go with DELETE for the second option. As long as you are locating a resource uniquely, you should try to treat the operation as being done on that resource. So in your case, the URL you are acting on is of Role's. So you DELETE the role from under the user. That is how I see it and it makes easy to read - METHOD on RESOURCE.

And also, if you do PUT, usually you replace the RESOURCE, which means you send the whole resource to the server.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but the URL's should not be amended as in the OP. RESTful URL's **must not include verbs (`register` and `revoke`)**. Verbs indicate an RPC or REST-RPC hybrid architecture.

Others have answered the verb-choice question well, but my 2p/2c is: -

- have a URL for the user-roles: `http://someapp/user-roles`
- POST to create a new mapping:

  - `POST http://someapp.com/user-roles/{userId}/{roleId}` - my preference
  - `POST http://someapp.com/user-roles/{userId};{roleId}`

    - composite path param
    - how to list roles-by-user?
  - `POST http://someapp.com/user-roles?user={userId}&role={roleId}`

    - how to list roles-by-user?
- DELETE to remove a mapping

  - `DELETE http://someapp.com/user-roles/{userId}/{roleId}` - my preference

POST should be for creating new resources, PUT is for updating existing